# Can't add internal API to KONG api gateway running on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, kong

I'm running Kong API gateway on GKE and trying to add my own service.

I have 3 pods

- `cassandra`
- `kong`
- `apiindex`

and  2 services(node ports)

- `apiindex` (80/443/8080 ports are open)
- `kong-proxy`(8000/8001/8443)

I'm trying to add `apiindex` api to API gateway using

> curl -i -X POST http://kong-proxy:8001/apis -d 'name=test' -d 'uris=/'
>   -d 'upstream_url=http://apiindex/'

But then `http://kong-proxy:8000/` returns

> 503 {"message": "Service unavailable"}

It works fine when I add some public website inside 
`curl -i -X POST http://kong-proxy:8001/apis -d 'name=test' -d 'uris=/' -d 'upstream_url=http://httpbin.org/'`

`curl http://apiindex/` returns 200 from `kong` pod.

Is it possible to add API using kong without exposing `apiindex` service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the fully qualified name of the service (FQDN) in kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

So instead of `apiindex` need to use `apiindex.default.svc.cluster.local`

> curl -i -X POST http://kong-proxy:8001/apis -d 'name=testapi' -d
>   'uris=/' -d 'upstream_url=http://apiindex.default.svc.cluster.local/'